# Qunit PropEqual but in Chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, qunit, chai

I am looking to compare properties of an object but I am moving to mocha away from QUnit and I was wondering if there was a chai equivalent of propEqual:

Example of that I need in chai:

```
QUnit.test( "propEqual test", function( assert ) {
  function Foo( x, y, z ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
  Foo.prototype.doA = function () {};
  Foo.prototype.doB = function () {};
  Foo.prototype.bar = 'prototype';

  var foo = new Foo( 1, "2", [] );
  var bar = {
    x : 1,
    y : "2",
    z : []
  };
  assert.propEqual( foo, bar, "Strictly the same properties without comparing objects constructors." );
});
```